# Calculating the difference between columns and adding that to the dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, difference

I am stumped on this question and not really sure how to ask it.  I have a table of Time Stamps as column headers.  Each row has a lat/lon point and a temperature for the time.  The data only comes in 3 hour increments, what I am trying to accomplish is to get an hourly temperature for the entire period.  I've been able to create a column with the time inbetween data.

Here is a sample of that dataframe

```
    Latitude | Longitude | 2021-6-11 10:00 | 2021-6-11 11:00 | 2021-6-11 12:00 | 2021-6-11 13:00 
   34.698848 | -104.9723 | 83.03           |     0           |      0          |   92.93
   34.702147 | -104.9177 | 81.95           |     0           |      0          |   92.93
```

What I am trying to accomplish is the columns that show zero to till with the temperature that would get from 10:00 to 13:00 as in 92.93-83.03 = 9.9 divide by 3 for both time slots = 3.3. The output dataframe should look like this

```
    Latitude | Longitude | 2021-6-11 10:00 | 2021-6-11 11:00 | 2021-6-11 12:00 | 2021-6-11 13:00
   34.698848 | -104.9723 | 83.03           |   86.33         |  86.93          | 92.93
   34.702147 | -104.9177 | 81.95           |   85.61         |  89.27          | 92.93
```

My dataframe continues on with columns every hour for 72 hours, but only every 3rd column has a value in it.  How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You are basically describing linear interpolation over regular intervals.
The following should work for your dataframe `df`:

```py
df = df.where(df!=0) # replace 0 with nan
df = df.interpolate(axis=1) # linear interpolation over nan values
```

My 2 cents: It would be better to create the new columns directly with `nan` values instead of `0` values just in case you have temperatures of 0°F.